# Handling a million data records in Angular Material paginator

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material

I am using Angular material paginator on the front end.  The Oracle table has 1.3 million records in the DB. I can't fetch all of them at a time(obvious), I need the paginator to make sure to display there are 130k pages assuming 10 records per page (130 k * 10 = 1.3 million). But the problem is material paginator is showing the total records to be the number of records available in the MatDataSource. In my case, I am fetching 30 records initially. The paginator is only showing 3 pages with 10 records per page.

But then, how can I tell the material paginator to show 130k pages and total records as 1.3 million (assuming 10 records per page) without fetching the actual data unless I go to a particular page?

Any leads will be very helpful.

PS - FYI, the backend is a Flask REST API

Below is the code for HTML and TS of the table component:
----- component.html code

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col">

    <mat-form-field>

      <input matInput (keyup)="onFilter($event)" placeholder="Search disputes">

    </mat-form-field>

    <table mat-table [dataSource]="disputesTableDataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

      <ng-container *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(disputesData[0])">

        <ng-container matColumnDef={{key}}>

          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{getColumnName(key)}}</th>

          <td (click)="onDisputeRowClick(dispute)" mat-cell *matCellDef="let dispute">{{dispute[key]}}</td>

        </ng-container>

      </ng-container>


      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>

      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></tr>

    </table>

    ***<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20, 30]" showFirstLastButtons>
    </mat-paginator>***

  </div>

</div>
```

----- component.ts code

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, Output, SimpleChanges, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';


import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';

import {MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';

import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';


import {AppConstants} from '@app/constants/AppConstants';

import {DBDispute} from '@app/feature-modules/disputes/models/dispute.model';


@Component({

 selector: 'app-mat-dispute-table',

 templateUrl: './mat-dispute-table.component.html',

 styleUrls: ['./mat-dispute-table.component.css']

})

export class MatDisputeTableComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

 columnsToDisplay: string[];

 disputesData: DBDispute[];

 disputesTableDataSource: MatTableDataSource<DBDispute>;

 objectKeys = Object.keys;


 @Input() tableOptions;
 @Output() paginationEv = new EventEmitter();

 @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;

 @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;



 constructor() {

 }



 ngOnInit() {

   this.columnsToDisplay = this.tableOptions.tableColNames;

   this.disputesData = [...this.tableOptions.tableData];

   this.disputesTableDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.disputesData);

   this.setSortAndPaginatorToMatTable();

   this.paginator.page

     .subscribe(ev => {

       this.paginationEv.emit(ev);

     });

 }


 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

   if (changes.tableOptions.previousValue !== changes.tableOptions.currentValue) {

     this.disputesTableDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(

       [...changes.tableOptions.currentValue.tableData]);



     this.columnsToDisplay = changes.tableOptions.currentValue.tableColNames;

     this.setSortAndPaginatorToMatTable();

   }

 }



 getColumnName(propName) {

   return this.tableHeaderMap[propName].colName;
 }

 onFilter({target: {value: targetValue}}) {

   this.disputesTableDataSource.filter = targetValue.trim().toLowerCase();

 }


 private setSortAndPaginatorToMatTable() {

   this.disputesTableDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

   this.disputesTableDataSource.sort = this.sort;

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer, here is the link of the detailed blog which helped me resolve my issue. As @Shank pointed, it has to do with paginator component length, along with some additional custom-data-source service creation.

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/

Answer (score 0):

Your API needs to return total number of records.

`MatPaginator` has length property, so you can use it to assign the total number of records to the length.

You can do this two ways:

1 in HTML:

```
<mat-paginator
   [length]="totalNumberOfRecords"
   [pageSizeOptions]="paginationNumbers"
>
</mat-paginator>
```

2 in TS:

```
/** Reference to pagination directive */
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true})
paginator: MatPaginator;

loadData() {
   //api call 
   //in response
   this.paginator.length = totalNumberOfRecords; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Shank, thanks for responding. I will give it a shot. Also, this does not need to fetch the records actually right?

Comment: I tried both the options, I was not able to see any changes in the Paginator

Comment: updated the question with the code, the problem is I have to disconnect the paginator with the data source (I am talking about this line, this.disputeTableDataSource.paginator = this.paginator), if I comment that line, the total length is getting displayed. But if I don't have this line, the table is displaying all the data irrespective of pagination size